# LINQ: Can we create a flat list from hierarchy

Tags: linq, xslt

OK... the title is correct...

**I dont want hierarchy from a flat list but exact reverse**

I have Folder class which has list of Folders in it held by property `Children`. So this is a typical hierarchy model.

I now want to flatten this list out... it will be an pre-order traversal i.e.

Assume

```
   A
   - A.1
   ----- A.1.1
   ----- A.1.2
   - A.2
   ----- A.2.1
   - A.3
   B
   - B.1
   - B.2
   ----- B.2.1
   ----- B.2.2
   ----------- B.2.2.1
   ----------- B.2.2.2
```

From this hierarchy, the flat list I am expecting is exactly the order in which it is appearing above!

If LINQ cant do this then can an XSLT make it flat into a list of xml-elements?

Comment: What do you mean, 'flat list'?

Comment: flat list means then parent list in the example above has only { A, B } and I want it converted to { A, A.1, A.1.1, A.1.2, A.2, A.2.1, ...., B.2.2, B.2.2.1, B.2.2.2 }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If LINQ cant do this then can an XSLT make it flat into a list of
>   xml-elements?

Several people have shown how to do this with LINQ.

**Here is a short and simple XSLT solution** that transforms an XML representation of the provided list of nested items into a flat ordered list of items:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
   <xsl:copy/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the XML-representation of your provided input**:

```
<t>
    <A>
        <A.1>
            <A.1.1/>
            <A.1.2/>
        </A.1>
        <A.2>
            <A.2.1/>
        </A.2>
        <A.3/>
    </A>
    <B>
        <B.1/>
        <B.2>
            <B.2.1/>
            <B.2.2>
                <B.2.2.1/>
                <B.2.2.2/>
            </B.2.2>
        </B.2>
    </B>
</t>
```

**The wanted, correctly ordered flat sequence is produced**:

```
<A/>
<A.1/>
<A.1.1/>
<A.1.2/>
<A.2/>
<A.2.1/>
<A.3/>
<B/>
<B.1/>
<B.2/>
<B.2.1/>
<B.2.2/>
<B.2.2.1/>
<B.2.2.2/>
```

**UPDATE**: Here is a *non-recursive* and even simpler XSLT solution (thanks to Andrew Welch for reminding me about this):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//*">
   <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This solution works without problem in cases where a recursive solution ends up with** *real stack overflow*.

Comment: Thx man... that was the fastest I observed for 10000 entries (total over hierarchy) than the LINQ.

Comment: @AngelWPF: You are welcome. This comes as no surprize as XSLT is a language specifically designed to process hierarchical (tree) data.

Comment: Does that time include the time taken to create the XML tree in the first place though? (Assuming that as I understand it this information is just in an object hierarchy to start with, *not* in XML.)

Comment: @_Jon-Skeet: XSLT 1.0 can be used to process *any tree-structured data* -- not just XML. I'd refer you to the books of another person from Reading -- @Michael Kay. Look at the chapter on processing genealogical data.

Comment: @AngelWPF: Given that there's been a fair amount of discussion between myself and Dimitre on this, could you post your benchmarking code somewhere? Could make for interesting discussion.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, nope that does not include serializing 10000 items into an XML. Actually my hierarchy list itself is de-serialized from XML response from server. So I converted it to a flat collection **after** the XSLT transformation that @DN suggested. :-)... I though LINQ may offer some relief but may be `PLINQ` can... sadly I am not using .Net 4.0 in my project.

Comment: @AngelWPF: Right - if you're starting with XML to start with, XSLT is probably the most appropriate solution. If you were starting with a collection of domain classes (as I *thought* your comment to my answer implied) then I don't think it would be. That's why it's so important to give context in the question - without that sort of information, it's very hard to give informed answers.

Comment: @AngelWPF: Having said that, using LINQ to XML and just a call to `doc.Descendants("Folder")` could be even simpler. Will edit my answer - although you still haven't told us what you're *doing* with the elements.

Comment: @_Jon-Skeet: A non-recursive solution (see my update) beats up almost any recursive solutions and works normally in cases where the latter end up with (real) stack overflow.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Actually I am creating a WPF DataGrid hierarchy tree view. For that I need this hierarchy converted flat list so that a random node / item is hidden when any of its ancestor node / item is not visible. Then when I "expand" one node I try to make immediate children visible. I already had a logic ready that I have tested on sample hierarchy flat list. But the logic to convert to a flat list was something I was missing hence I raised this post.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Now that we've got a *bit* more context, it sounds like you've actually got XML to start with. However, we still don't know what processing you're performing on the elements. XSLT *may* be the right approach, but another would be to use LINQ to XML and its `Descendants` method:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
var descendants = doc.Descendants("Folder");
// Use descendants now
```

That *may* end up being even simpler than the XSLT approach. For example, if you want to transform it into a `List<string>` by taking an attribute from each element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
var names = doc.Descendants("Folder")
               .Select(x => (strong) x.Attribute("name"))
               .ToList();
```

One downside is that this will still load the whole XML file into memory as `XElement` (etc) objects. It's entirely possible that the XSLT version can handle this in a streaming fashion with more efficient memory usage. Dimitre can no doubt give more information if this is relevant.

---

There's nothing in LINQ to flatten *multiple* levels of hierarchy without performing recursion yourself. `SelectMany` performs *one* level of flattening, but you'd need to recurse to flatten your multi-level hierarchy to a single list.

Now if you're using LINQ to XML, that *does* support it very easily - you can just use the `Descendants` method:

```
var allFolders = root.Descendants("Folder");
```

To write something similar for your domain class though, you'd need to write more code. If you can give more information about what you've *really* got (XML or domain classes) we may be able to help you more.

EDIT: Okay, it sounds like XML is a red herring here. But finding all the descendants is pretty easy. You *can* do it using iterator blocks, but that becomes pretty unpleasantly inefficient fairly quickly. Here's another simple alternative:

```
public IList<Folder> SelfAndDescendants()
{
    List<Folder> ret = new List<Folder>();
    AddSelfAndDescendants(ret);
    return ret;
}

private void AddSelfAndDescendants(IList<Folder> list)
{
    list.Add(this);
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        AddSelfAndDescendants(list);
    }
}
```

You can tailor the exact algorithm based on the order in which you want to get the children back.

Comment: I could serialzie my class to XML also if someone gives me a flat list maker XSLT. But I was thinking of using LINQ on my domain class objects i.e. `class Folder { List<Folder> Children; }`

Comment: @AngelWPF: See my edit for a way of easily building up a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SelectMany to flatten a heirarchy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a linq-style extension method which does what you're asking (no recursion, cycles handled).

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> WalkTreeDepthFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
       Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childFunction)
    {
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
        HashSet<T> seenIt = new HashSet<T>();
        Stack<T> toVisit = new Stack<T>();

        foreach (T item in source.Reverse())
        {
            toVisit.Push(item);
        }

        while (toVisit.Any())
        {
            T item = toVisit.Pop();
            if (!seenIt.Contains(item))
            {
                seenIt.Add(item);
                foreach (T child in childFunction(item).Reverse())
                {
                    toVisit.Push(child);
                }
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This would by my first try:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Folder> SelfPlusChildren(Folder f)
    {
        return new[] {f}.Concat(f.Children.SelectMany(SelfPlusChildren));
    }
```

Comment: WIll try and let you know. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple extension method to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Folder> GetFolders(this Folder rootFolder)
{
    yield return rootFolder;

    foreach (var child in rootFolder.Children)
        foreach(var folder in GetFolders(child))
            yield return folder;
}
```

Or shorter using `SelectMany()`:

```
public static IEnumerable<Folder> GetFolders(this Folder rootFolder)
{
    yield return rootFolder;

    foreach (var folder in rootFolder.Children.SelectMany(GetFolders))
        yield return folder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard implementation in .Net framework, but you can implement it yourself.

Here is how you can do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FlattenTree<T>(this T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren)
{
    var state = new Stack<T>();
    state.Push(root);

    while (state.Count != 0)
    {
        T top = state.Pop();
        yield return top;

        IEnumerable<T> children = getChildren(top) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        foreach (T child in children.Reverse())
        {
            state.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```